# jQuery disable button behaviour once selected

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

I have two buttons side by side that open separate bits of content below, however I want the button associated with the visible bit of content to do nothing once you selected it again.

At the moment when the button is clicked again, the content closes. (Basically there always needs to be content showing.)

Also, would it be possible to have the First Button content open as default?

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/0ptdm8qs/2/

Any suggestions appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.firstbutton').click(function(){
    if($('#first').is(':visible')) {
        $('#first').hide();
    }
    else {
    $('#second').hide();
    $('#first').fadeIn();
    }
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.secondbutton').click(function() {
    if ($('#second').is(':visible')) {
          $('#second').fadeOut();
        if ($("#second").data('lastClicked') !== this) {
           $('#second').fadeIn();
        }
    } 
    else {
        $('#first').hide();
        $('#second').fadeIn();
    }
    $("#second").data('lastClicked', this);
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function() {  
    $('.button').not(this).removeClass('buttonactive');
    $(this).toggleClass('buttonactive');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove all the toggle code, add the .buttonactive class to .firstbutton and set display: block; for #first.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.firstbutton').click(function(){
        $('#second').hide();
        $('#first').fadeIn();        
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.secondbutton').click(function() {
   $('#first').hide();
   $('#second').fadeIn();  
      $("#second").data('lastClicked', this);
 });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function() {  
        $(this).addClass('buttonactive');
        $('.button').not(this).removeClass('buttonactive');        
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 background: #fff;
 height: auto;
}
#first {
 display: block;
 width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #EC644B;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}
#second {
 display: none;
 width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #446CB3;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}
.button {
 width: 250px;
 display: inline-block;
 clear: both;
 margin: 10px 0;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 49px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.firstbutton {
 background-color: #EC644B;
}
.secondbutton {
 background-color: #446CB3;
}
.buttonactive {
 color: #000;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0b1.js"></script>
  
  <div id="container">
    
 <span class="button firstbutton buttonactive">First Button</span>
 <span class="button secondbutton">Second Button</span>
  
 <div id="first">ONE</div>
 <div id="second">TWO</div>
    
 </div>
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was after! Thanks a lot!